# как вызвать функцию из другой функции и изменить параметр?

Tags: javascript

```js
var result = 0;

function firstFunc(a) {
  function secondFunc(b) {
    result = a + b;
  }
  secondFunc();
}

firstFunc(10);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: так ты уже вызываешь и все меняется

Comment: мне нужна вторая функция чтоб дать параметр

Comment: тогда просто верни эту функцию: вместо `secondFunc();` -> `return secondFunc;` - а потом вызови ее с нужным параметром

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/bind#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3

Comment: function firstFunc(a) {
  function secondFunc(b) {
    result = a + b;
  }
 return secondFunc();
}

firstFunc(10);
secondFunc(10);

Comment: Читайте по ссылке выше,как уже писали выше вторая функция будет доступна если ее вернуть и результат будет доступен если его тоже вернуть function firstFunc(a) { return function secondFunc(b) { return result = a + b; }

Comment: спасибо за информацию